# What causes this discrepancy in type checking behavior based on interface declaration style?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

It seems there is a discrepancy in how interfaces are checked when they are declared with properties versus methods. Specifically, assuming some object whose shape doesn't really matter:

```
interface ObjectInQuestion {
  value: any
}
```

these interfaces:

```
interface FirstInterface {
  callback(obj: Partial<ObjectInQuestion>): void;
}

interface SecondInterface {
  callback: (obj: Partial<ObjectInQuestion>) => void;
}
```

typecheck differently:

```
function takesFirstInterfacePasses(_: FirstInterface) { }

function takesSecondInterfaceFails(_: SecondInterface) { }

function thisTakesEntireObject(_: ObjectInQuestion) { }

function whyDoTheseFunctionsCheckDifferently() {

  takesFirstInterfacePasses({ callback: thisTakesEntireObject })

  takesSecondInterfaceFails({ callback: thisTakesEntireObject })
}
```

Could someone help me understand why this is?

Here's a link to a [repro in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgJIgCKArhAM5jAD2IyA3gLABQyyAbnADakBcycIAJ7MAvs2ahIsRCgBiwKBQJT4Ses1YIundIgDWACipY+ABThRKXADwZsuAiXKUaAPgCUfNlWAATANyi4kyS0KooAMo4NL7KYTLqLMhanDr6fEYmyOaWwDZ2OPhEpBTUIB7IALyu7D4BQUzMMMQguGXIYHB65PKKRSoy5mRk5AYA+ny9SuDxSO70yGKNTM2tLrSd3WRRCDFx0kiycMCcZON8O3szBxDzdIvBq200HQAWwGQAKl3kAKLgCggBVw5zQWEKjhK6zuD2WT3WyAA7q9BAARKifV7kCCyFrPEBkADCWIQelRwBgMGgEHAnEEBjuwVYmx6CmmAyQQxGZ3uKTSpL4YHeXx+ZH+lCgQPBuEW7iZHVFlxAsWu4SOJx5yW0ugFbw+3y24sBwLAsoaQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled, the parameters of *non-method* functions are compared *contravariantly* for added type safety, while parameters of *methods* are still compared *bivariantly* to support convenient yet unsafe type hierarchies (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for a description of variance).

In

```
interface FirstInterface {
  callback(obj: Partial<ObjectInQuestion>): void;
}
```

`callback` is a method, so `obj` is compared bivariantly, and thus `takesFirstInterfacePasses({ callback: thisTakesEntireObject })` is accepted, even though `thisTakesEntireObject` expects something more specific than `Partial<ObjectInQuestion>`, a potentially unsafe operation.

Whereas in

```
interface SecondInterface {
  callback: (obj: Partial<ObjectInQuestion>) => void;
}
```

`callback` is a function-valued property, and thus `obj` is checked contravariantly, and so `takesSecondInterfaceFails({ callback: thisTakesEntireObject })` is rejected.

---

In case it matters, here's the type safety issue.  Let's make the `value` property more specific:

```
interface ObjectInQuestion {
  value: string
}
```

And let's have `thisTakesEntireObject()` actually do something that depends on that property being a `string`:

```
function thisTakesEntireObject(_: ObjectInQuestion) {
  console.log(_.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

And let's have your `takesFirstInterfacePasses()` function actually call the `callback` method on a partial object, which should work:

```
function takesFirstInterfacePasses(_: FirstInterface) {
  console.log("calling")
  _.callback({}) // RUNTIME ERROR: _.value is undefined 
}
```

Then when you call `whyDoTheseFunctionsCheckDifferently()` you will get a runtime error, when `undefined` is checked for its non-existent `toUpperCase()` method.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Appreciate the docs link explaining this! I expected both calls to give red squigglies for the reasons you mention, so I was surprised when it didn't error when declared as a method... The design decision about bivariance ("The stricter checking applies to all function types, except [...] in method [...] declarations. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array<T>) continue to mostly relate covariantly.") is still a bit odd (as you mention, "convenient yet unsafe"), but maybe this isn't the forum for that discussion :D Thanks again!