# The Typescript typechecker distinguishes between method and function property in an unusual way. Is this a bug?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

This situation is as follows:

```
interface Handler1<S>{
  handle(s: S): any
}

interface Handler2<S> {
  handler: (s: S) => any
}

declare function higherOrder1(handler: Handler1<unknown>): unknown
declare function higherOrder2(handler: Handler2<unknown>): unknown

declare const h1: Handler1<number>
declare const h2: Handler2<number>

higherOrder1(h1) // Typechecks, bug???
higherOrder2(h2) // Does not typecheck, as expected
```

It seems to me that neither `higherOrder1(h1)` nor `higherOrder2(h2)` should type check, as `unknown` is not assignable to `number`. Is there a reason why `higherOrder1(h1)` type checks?

This seems to be an issue specifically with the `handle(s: S): T` notation. Working directly with functions behaves as expected.

```
declare function higherOrder3(fn: (u: unknown) => number): unknown
const fn1 = (x: number) => x
function fn2(x: number){
  return x
}

// Neither of these three type check, as expected.
higherOrder3(fn1)
higherOrder3(fn2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "typecheck"? It throws an error?

Comment: methods are bivariant, however, function properties in an interface are contravariant in TS

Comment: Yep that's it VLAZ. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934661/what-causes-this-discrepancy-in-type-checking-behavior-based-on-interface-declar) brought me to  [strict-function-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types).

Comment: @vera. I mean the opposite, I think (thought) it ought to throw an error as I expected contravariant function type checking for methods, but apparently strict-function-types still checks methods covariantly.